# SQL ignore inner query if it returns nothing

Tags: sql

I have this table below where I keep history of order validation:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4QDs.png)

I want to select all records after the rejected status if the rejected status exists.

I have tried this query:

```
select * 
from status_timeline
where validation_date > (select max(validation_date) 
                         from status_timeline 
                         where order = 1345 and status = 'REJECT')
  and order = 111;
```

It works as expected only when there's a status `REJECT`, I want to ignore the subquery if it returns nothing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `max` aggregate function returns `NULL` if there are no matching records. Since you can't compare a `NULL` value to anything, you either need to do a null check in your where clause or wrap your subquery in the `ISNULL` function and return an arbitrary old date to check against

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Read about [MCVE for SQL queries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). And add the tag of your database.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` here

```
select * 
from status_timeline
where validation_date >
 coalesce(
   (select max(validation_date) from status_timeline where order = 1345 and status = 'REJECT'),
   '19700101'
 ) and order = 111;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a `NOT EXISTS` query.

```
select * 
from status_timeline st1
where not exists (select 1
                  from status_timeline st2
                  where st2.order = 1345 and st2.status = 'REJECT'
                    and st2.validation_date > st1.validation_date)
  and order = 111;
```

Or do a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select st1.*
from status_timeline st1
left join status_timeline st2
    on  st2.order = 1345 and st2.status = 'REJECT'
    and st2.validation_date > st1.validation_date
where st1.order = 111
  and st2.validation_date is null;
```